# Timon - Step Form Wizard: jQuery is working but $ is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I bought a WordPress-Theme and need to realize a complex form with multiple steps. For this I'm writing a plugin and bought "Timon - Step Form Wizard". So I included the CSS and JS files, but get an error:

> VM5199 tsf-wizard-plugin.js?ver=1.0:77Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined

It happens in the latest line of the following snippet:

```
jQuery.fn.tsfWizard = function (options) {

var defaults =
{
    stepStyle: 'style1',       // grumpy step indicator all styles
    stepEffect: 'basic',
    showStepNum: true,
    stepTransition: true,      //true or false
    validation: false,         //true or false
    navPosition: 'top',        //'bottom' or top,right,left
    height: 'auto',            //'auto' or any height (600px,400px etc)
    showButtons: true,
    manySteps: false,
    prevBtn: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i> PREV',
    nextBtn: 'NEXT <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>',
    finishBtn: 'FINISH',
    disableSteps: 'none',       //all | after_current | before_current | none    
    onSlideChanged: function (e) { },
    onNextClick: function (e) { },
    onPrevClick: function (e) { },
    onPrevClick: function (e) { },
    onFinishClick: function (e) { }
};

var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
```

In the browser console, it says me that $ is undefined but jQuery works:

```
typeof $
"undefined"
typeof jQuery
"function"
```

jQuery is loaded from the WordPress includes:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://127.0.0.1/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4'></script>
```

I use jQuery since a longer time but never had those issue. What could destroy the $ variable? And how can I fix this?

EDIT:

I added

```
<script>$ = jQuery;</script>
```

before ALL other scripts (jQuery included) were loaded, this fixed the issue. But I can't understand why this occurs.

Comment: The issue is because you have used another library which has overridden the `$` variable.

Comment: But I have no other librarys, only modernizr, jQuery and some jQuery plugins. And when another library overrides the $ variable, then it has to be some function behind it. Seems like $ doesn't do something, as it is undefined.

Comment: It's relatively common in wordpress to use noconflict, which removes `$` leaving just `jQuery`

Answer (score 0):

You probably have `$.noConflict()` somewhere in your code, which disables the usage of jQuery through $.

It's used when multiple libraries are used together and may clash, because they all use the $ to access their APIs.